# Почему не выводится результат программы?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ALLOCATE_SIZE 1000

int input_array(int *A, int max_size)
{
int top = 0;
while  (true)
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x == 0 || top == max_size) break;
    A[top] = x;
    top++;
}
return top;
}
void print_array(int *A, int N)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
        printf("%3d", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
void insert_sort(int *A, int N)
{
     // перебираем цикл для доступа к элементам //
    // начиная со второго элемента //
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        // вставка начинается с позиции равной i //
        // важно помнить старый i //
        int k = i;
        // двигаем влево пока кто-то есть слева //
        // и тот, кто слева, он больше, чем A[k] //
        while(k > 0 || A[k - 1] > A[k])
        {
            // далее меняем местами через временную переменную //
            int tmp = A[k - 1];
            A[k - 1] = A[k];
            A[k] = tmp;
            // сдвигаем позицию влево //
            k -= 1;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    printf("Введите числа: ");
    int A[ALLOCATE_SIZE];
    int N;

    N = input_array(A, ALLOCATE_SIZE);
    insert_sort(A, N);
    print_array(A, N);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция сортировки нерабочая.
Цикл уходит за границы массива в отрицательную сторону.
На первом шаге `k==1`, потом в цикле она становится `k==0`.
И поскольку в условии стоит логическое `или`, в условии цикла вы делаете проверку
`A[-1] > A[0]`. Это уже неопределенное поведение, чаще всего крах программы.
А если что-то, что лежит в памяти по адресу `A[-1]` случайно больше `A[0]`, вы начинаете сравнивать `A[-2] > A[-1]`. Мало того что сравнивать, начинаете менять значения.

```
while(k > 0 || A[k - 1] > A[k])
{
   k -= 1;
}
```

Решается просто.

```
while(k > 0)
{
  if(A[k - 1] > A[k])
  { // здесь обмен значений
  }
  k--;
}
```

И вместо обмена значений вручную я бы рекомендовал использовать `swap()`

Comment: Спасибо! Думаю следует просто быть более внимательным...